# Fabric.js how to set opacity of lines

Tags: fabricjs

Using the `fabric.js` library, I can set line width and color as follows:

```
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 5;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "#f00";
```

Is there a way to set the opacity too? Couldn't find anything in the documentation, neither on the net anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a hexadecimal color code, you can set `color` to use `rgba`, like below:

```
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)';
```

[Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e87eutde/)

Comment: Thanks, you just made my day!